# How to Hide Export XMl Opition in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, grid, custom-admin-grid

I Want to Hide Export XML Option in Magento 2 Admin Grid

I only Want to Export CSV File and i am using Custom Controller for Conversion

Need Help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_product_listing.vendor_module_product_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_product_listing.vendor_module_product_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">spinner_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">refresh</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Refresh Cache</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">vendor_module/product/refresh</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sticky" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <exportButton class="Magento\Ui\Component\ExportButton" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/export" displayArea="dataGridActions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="csv" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visibility" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">csv</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">CSV</item>
                            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">vendor_module/product/gridtocsv</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="xml" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visibility" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </exportButton>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="vendor_module/product/massDelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete Post</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected items?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sizesConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">vendor_module/js/grid/paging/sizes</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </listingToolbar>
    <dataSource name="vendor_module_product_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\UI\DataProvider\Product\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_product_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">image_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">image_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <columns name="spinner_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_product_listing.vendor_module_product_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
                </item>
                <item name="editorConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_product_listing.vendor_module_product_listing.spinner_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">image_id</item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_product_listing.vendor_module_product_listing.spinner_columns</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_product_listing.vendor_module_product_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">image_id</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">vendor_module/js/grid/columns/multiselect</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Select</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="serial_no">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Serial No</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="name" class="Vendor\Module\UI\Component\Listing\Module\Product\Column\Thumbnail">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/thumbnail</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                    <item name="altField" xsi:type="string">image_id</item>
                    <item name="has_preview" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="file_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">50</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="altField" xsi:type="string">image_id</item>
                    <item name="has_preview" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="file_path">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">50</item>
                    <item name="altField" xsi:type="string">image_id</item>
                    <item name="has_preview" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Path</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="added_at">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">50</item>
                    <item name="altField" xsi:type="string">image_id</item>
                    <item name="has_preview" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Uploaded At</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Vendor\Module\UI\Component\Listing\Module\Product\Column\Actions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">image_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a solution by using custom class for export button.

```
<exportButton name="export_button" class="Vendor\Module\Component\ExportButton">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options_custom" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="cvs" xsi:type="array">                    
                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string">csv</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">CSV</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="string">vendor_module/product/gridtocsv</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</exportButton>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Component/ExportButton.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Component;

/**
 * Class ExportButton
 */
class ExportButton extends \Magento\Ui\Component\ExportButton
{
    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function prepare()
    {
        $context = $this->getContext();
        $config = $this->getData('config');
        if (isset($config['options'])) {
            $options = [];
            foreach ($config['options'] as $option) {
                /*Removed xml from here*/
                if($option['value'] != 'xml'){
                    $additionalParams = $this->getAdditionalParams($config, $context);
                    $option['url'] = $this->urlBuilder->getUrl($option['url'], $additionalParams);
                    $options[] = $option;
                }
            }
            $config['options'] = $options;
            $this->setData('config', $config);
        }
        parent::prepare();
    }
}
```

Comment: i did this already But its not working

Comment: do you ever tried that?

Comment: Yes and working fine in my setup..Can you pls update your code?

Comment: Check, is there any other exportButton tag in your file?

Comment: not that is the only one

Comment: Check your url is correct? `frontname/controller/gridtocsv`

Comment: ya CSV is WOrking Fine i just want to Hide Excel XML

Comment: Is that possible to post full code of your xml?

Comment: seee updated question

Comment: I have checked....This cannot be done using xml only...You have to create custom component to achieve this.

Comment: can u help please?

Comment: Ok I will update

Comment: Updated answer without creating a component..Pls check

Answer (score 7):

Add a class to exportButton component:

```
<exportButton name="export_button" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\ExportButton">
```

And create a class which extends Magento component:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component;

class ExportButton extends \Magento\Ui\Component\ExportButton
{
    public function prepare()
    {
        $config = $this->getConfig();
        $options = $config['options'];

        if (!array_key_exists('xml', $options)) {
            parent::prepare();
            return;
        }

        unset($options['xml']);

        $config['options'] = $options;

        $this->setConfig($config);

        parent::prepare();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can update your `XML` file with this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_product_listing.vendor_module_product_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_product_listing.vendor_module_product_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">spinner_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">refresh</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Refresh Cache</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">vendor_module/product/refresh</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sticky" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <exportButton class="Magento\Ui\Component\ExportButton" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/export" displayArea="dataGridActions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/grid/export</item>
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="csv" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visibility" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">csv</item>
                            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">CSV</item>
                            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">vendor_module/product/gridtocsv</item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="xml" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visibility" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </exportButton>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="vendor_module/product/massDelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete Post</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected items?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sizesConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">vendor_module/js/grid/paging/sizes</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </listingToolbar>
    <dataSource name="vendor_module_product_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\UI\DataProvider\Product\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_product_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">image_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">image_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <columns name="spinner_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_product_listing.vendor_module_product_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current</item>
                </item>
                <item name="editorConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_product_listing.vendor_module_product_listing.spinner_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">image_id</item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_product_listing.vendor_module_product_listing.spinner_columns</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">startEdit</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendor_module_product_listing.vendor_module_product_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">image_id</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">vendor_module/js/grid/columns/multiselect</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Select</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="serial_no">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Serial No</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="name" class="Vendor\Module\UI\Component\Listing\Module\Product\Column\Thumbnail">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/thumbnail</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                    <item name="altField" xsi:type="string">image_id</item>
                    <item name="has_preview" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="file_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">50</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="altField" xsi:type="string">image_id</item>
                    <item name="has_preview" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="file_path">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">50</item>
                    <item name="altField" xsi:type="string">image_id</item>
                    <item name="has_preview" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Path</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="added_at">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">50</item>
                    <item name="altField" xsi:type="string">image_id</item>
                    <item name="has_preview" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Uploaded At</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Vendor\Module\UI\Component\Listing\Module\Product\Column\Actions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">image_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

I've added this line

```
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/grid/export</item>
```

In this section..

```
<exportButton class="Magento\Ui\Component\ExportButton" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/export" displayArea="dataGridActions">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/grid/export</item>
            <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="csv" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visibility" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="value" xsi:type="string">csv</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">CSV</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="string">vendor_module/product/gridtocsv</item>
                </item>
                <item name="xml" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visibility" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</exportButton>
```

Now you need to create one `js` and `template` file on this path..

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/js/grid/export.js

Content for this file is..

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'uiElement'
], function ($, _, Element) {
    'use strict';

    return Element.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Vendor_Module/grid/exportButton',
            selectProvider: 'ns = ${ $.ns }, index = ids',
            checked: '',
            additionalParams: [],
            modules: {
                selections: '${ $.selectProvider }'
            }
        },

        /** @inheritdoc */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super()
                .initChecked();
        },

        /** @inheritdoc */
        initConfig: function () {
            this._super();

            _.each(this.additionalParams, function (value, key) {
                key = 'additionalParams.' + key;
                this.imports[key] = value;
            }, this);

            return this;
        },

        /** @inheritdoc */
        initObservable: function () {
            this._super()
                .observe('checked');

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Checks first option if checked not defined.
         *
         * @returns {Object}
         */
        initChecked: function () {
            if (!this.checked()) {
                this.checked(
                    this.options[0].value
                );
            }

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Compose params object that will be added to request.
         *
         * @returns {Object}
         */
        getParams: function () {
            var selections = this.selections(),
                data = selections ? selections.getSelections() : null,
                itemsType,
                result = {};

            if (data) {
                itemsType = data.excludeMode ? 'excluded' : 'selected';
                result.filters = data.params.filters;
                result.search = data.params.search;
                result.namespace = data.params.namespace;
                result[itemsType] = data[itemsType];
                _.each(this.additionalParams, function (param, key) {
                    result[key] = param;
                });

                if (!result[itemsType].length) {
                    result[itemsType] = false;
                }
            }

            return result;
        },

        /**
         * Find checked option.
         *
         * @returns {Object}
         */
        getActiveOption: function () {
            return _.findWhere(this.options, {
                value: this.checked()
            });
        },

        /**
         * Build option url.
         *
         * @param {Object} option
         * @returns {String}
         */
        buildOptionUrl: function (option) {
            var params = this.getParams();

            if (!params) {
                return 'javascript:void(0);';
            }

            return option.url + '?' + $.param(params);
            //TODO: MAGETWO-40250
        },

        /**
         * Redirect to built option url.
         */
        applyOption: function () {
            var option = this.getActiveOption(),
                url = this.buildOptionUrl(option);

            location.href = url;

        }
    });
});
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/web/template/grid/exportButton.html

Content for this file is...

```
<div class="admin__action-dropdown-wrap admin__data-grid-action-export" collapsible>
    <button class="admin__action-dropdown" type="button" toggleCollapsible>
        <span class="admin__action-dropdown-text" translate="'Export'"/>
    </button>
    <div class="admin__action-dropdown-menu admin__data-grid-action-export-menu">
        <div class="admin__field admin__field-option" outereach="options">
            <!-- ko if: label == 'CSV' -->
                <input class="admin__control-radio" type="radio"
                    data-bind="
                        attr: {
                            id: ++ko.uid
                        },
                        checkedValue: value,
                        checked: $parent.checked"/>
                <label class="admin__field-label" text="label" attr="for: ko.uid"/>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
        <div class="admin__action-dropdown-footer-main-actions">
            <button class="action-tertiary" type="button" translate="'Cancel'" closeCollapsible/>
            <button class="action-secondary" type="button" translate="'Export'" click="applyOption"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After adding above code you need to run below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Now you can see only `CSV` option in your backend grid.

**Output :**

[image]

Hope this will help you!

Comment: But it will remove XML export option from all the grids.

Comment: @Ranganathan, I've updated my code and that will only works for single grid export. :)